# I'm stuck inside a platform, is there any way to get out?

Tags: worms-crazy-golf

Looks like I hit the lift suspension thing (on Brittania level 12) from just the right angle, and I'm stuck between it and the platform or inside the platform or something.  Can I get down without restarting the level?  (I was trying for points and don't want to spend time re-getting them.)  I've tried a few shots in different directions with no luck.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Overdrive shots have magic powers.  One straight out to the left knocked the ball out even though a regular shot did not.  That said, I wasn't able to get unstuck from here:

[image: screenshot]

Hopefully they fix this with a patch.